# How to Set Kotlin Integration Test Source Directory Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Please note there are several similar questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51876992) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52904603) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51455726) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52074532)) regarding how to set source-set for integration tests in Gradle but none of them is using `JvmTestSuite`.

I've got my `build.gradle.kt` configured as below (please let me know if full script is needed to answer my question):

```kotlin
testing {
    suites {
        val test by getting(JvmTestSuite::class) {
            useJUnitJupiter()
        }

        val integration by registering(JvmTestSuite::class) {
            testType.set(TestSuiteType.INTEGRATION_TEST)

            dependencies {
                implementation(project)
            }

            sources {
                java {
                    setSrcDirs(listOf("src/it/java"))
                }
                resources {
                    setSrcDirs(listOf("src/it/resources"))
                }
            }

            targets {
                all {
                    testTask.configure {
                        shouldRunAfter(test)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Having that, Gradle finds my Java tests in `java` folder and runs them correctly. Now my question is how to set the source directory for `kotlin` folder. The same syntax doesn't seem to work. I also tried different solutions found on the web, but none works. Thanks.

**Update**
It seems to be as simple as:

```
java {
    setSrcDirs(listOf("src/it/kotlin"))
}
```

I'll wait if someone else has a better answer.